# PDF in documentclass{book}

Tags: pdf, bookmarks

How can I make the PDF of my book written under `\documentclass{book}` open in PDF with on the left sidebar a table of contents and clickable markers for chapters? I see it with books generated using Tufte's method and Springer textbooks.

Comment: Use the `hyperref` package.

Answer (score 1):

Explanations taken from Sebastian Rahtz, Heiko Oberdiek et al.

Play around with these options as you like! See more information [here](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyperref). In most cases, you should load `hyperref` as last package.

In some cases, you will have to enable the bookmarks view in your PDF-reader. E.g. for SumatraPDF this would be the key stroke `F12`.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage[%
    %,bookmarks=false % make bookmarks
    %,bookmarksnumbered=true % putsection numbers in bookmarks
    %,bookmarksopen=true % open up bookmark tree
    %,bookmarksopenlevel=3 % level to which bookmarks are open
    %,bookmarkstype=toc % to specify which ‘toc’ file to mimic
    %,CJKbookmarks=true % if you need CJK bookmarks
]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\chapter{chapter1}
\kant[1]
\section{section1}
\kant[2]
\chapter{chapter2}
\kant[3]
\section{section2}
\kant[4]
\end{document}
```